# foreach through a dataTable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable, datarow

Can someone show me how to loop through a datatable for a value of 'true' and if that value is true set it to a string? I am not sure how to write it and I started to write a foreach. Can someome show me how to finsh it with their own values?

```
foreach (DataRowView drv in dttestGroups.DefaultView)
{
    foreach (DataRow rowSec in ud.m_UsertestGroupsTable.Rows)
    {
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (DataRowView drv in dttestGroups.DefaultView)
{
    foreach (DataRow rowSec in ud.m_UsertestGroupsTable.Rows)
    {
        {
             if( (bool)rowSec["ColumnName"] == true)
             // or if((bool)rowSec[columnIndex] == true)
             {
                 //do something. 
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. You have to know the the column is of type `bool`. otherwise it will throw an exception.
2. You *can't* set the same column's value to a string.